# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'DeferredAttribute' django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good afternoon community,

I am new to Django and in order to practice, I am building a financial website. The goal is that the user will insert data regarding company x, e.g. Apple, and the website will perform some metrics calculations to return to the user.

I have two models so far:

```
class Company(models.Model):
#Company data
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
outstanding_shares = models.IntegerField()
share_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places=2)
revenue = models.IntegerField()
expenses = models.IntegerField()
total_assets = models.IntegerField()
total_liabilities = models.IntegerField()
current_assets = models.IntegerField()
current_liabilities = models.IntegerField()
operating_cashflows = models.IntegerField()
capex = models.IntegerField()

#Date of creation
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)    
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name

class Market_Cap(Company):          
market_cap= Company.share_price * Company.outstanding_shares
```

When I run python manage.py check I get the following error:

Market_Cap
market_cap= Company.share_price * Company.outstanding_shares
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'DeferredAttribute'

Any hints as to how I can solve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method in your `Company` model like that:

```py
@property
def market_cap(self):
    return self.share_price * self.outstanding_shares
```